# Using Vert.x to read file line by line (AsyncFile and RecordParser help)

Tags: asynchronous, inputstream, vert.x

I'm trying to use Vert.x to read a large file from the file system and process it line by line. From the Core docs, I think the way to do this is through an `AsyncFile` and a `RecordParser`. Ideally, I'd like to `Pump` the data (to avoid back-pressure), but `RecordParser` is not a `WriteStream`:

```java
AsyncFile asyncFile = vertx.fileSystem().openBlocking(/*path and options*/);

RecordParser recordParser = RecordParser.newDelimited("\n", bufferedLine -> {
  // Do something per line
});

Pump.pump(asyncFile, recordParser).start(); // Error - RecordParser cannot be converted to WriteStream
```

So I guess I have to do my own pumping? I tried something like:

```java
RecordParser recordParser = RecordParser.newDelimited("\n", bufferedLine -> {
  // Do something per line
  // I can see this code get run
})
.exceptionHandler(cause -> {
  // Do I need this? What are the repercussions if I don't have this handler? Are exceptions just lost?
})
.endHandler(_void -> {
  // This never gets called!
});

asyncFile.handler(recordParser); // Crazy Java8 syntax passes recordParser.handle to this handler :)
```

However, I'm not sure my file is being closed as the `recordParser.endHandler` never gets called (although I can see the line handler being called).

What am I doing wrong? Is the file not being closed? I tried adding an `endHandler` to `asyncFile` and closing it, but that didn't work.

Ideally, I'd rather get `Pump` to work. Is there any way to use `Pump` in this scenario?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: Excuse the ["crosspost"](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/vertx/JDvRkhuGj4c/discussion).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do with `AsyncFile` and `RecordParser` as you said.

```
RecordParser recordParser = RecordParser.newDelimited("\n", bufferedLine -> {
  System.out.println("bufferedLine = " + bufferedLine);
});

asyncFile.handler(recordParser)
    .endHandler(v -> {
      asyncFile.close();
      System.out.println("Done");
    });
```

If you go this way, you should set an exception handler on the `AsyncFile`, not on the `RecordParser`.

With the code above, the file will be closed properly.

> However, I'm not sure my file is being closed as the recordParser.endHandler never gets called (although I can see the line handler being called).

Actually, the `endHandler` and the `exceptionHandler` will only get called if the `RecordParser` is created by wrapping another `ReadStream`. In your case, they are not necessary.

Also, regarding your comment:

> // Crazy Java8 syntax passes recordParser.handle to this handler :)

This is not a Java 8 trick, it's just that `AsyncFile.handler()` expects a `Handler<Buffer>` and `RecordParser` implements this interface.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Also, missed the Handler implementation =)

Comment: Do you have any comment on whether I need `Pump` in this case? Any examples of how to implement it?

Comment: You would need a `Pump` if you would transfer the buffers to a `WriteStream`, like another file or an HTTP server response. In this case, you would create the `RecordParser` by [wrapping](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/parsetools/RecordParser.html#newDelimited-java.lang.String-io.vertx.core.streams.ReadStream-) the `AsyncFile`. The `RecordParser` could then be used as any other `ReadStream` with a `Pump`.

Comment: How to read the very last row if it doesn't contain \n character but EOF

Comment: If it doesn't emit the last item then I think it's a bug